# jquery mobile app does not show styled text on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, cordova

I am trying to build my first project for iOS using PhoneGap. I have picked up an example from this page:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/579532/Building-an-iPhone-App-using-jQuery-Mobile

And my code looks like this after changing reference to 1.4.1 ans 1.9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Task Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tasksPage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Edit</a>
            <h1>Task Timer-1</h1>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="taskList" data-role="listview">
                <li onclick="alert(1)">Task 1</li>
                <li onclick="alert(2)">Task 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page, if you copy to an html file will display formatted text. However when I copy the App to iPhone it displays simple text.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just solved the issue.

I made a reference to cordova.js in main html file. And as a precaution copied cordova.js to www folder. And the text started appearing formatted the JQM way.